# Changing NAD27 to NAD83 in R, Error in proj4string

Tags: coordinate-system, r, nad83

I am having trouble changing latitude/longitude data (from spreadsheet dataset) from NAD27 to NAD83. I am using R. The spreadsheet has 2 million coordinates so I can't upload the data for you all to work with. This is the code I have so far:

```
lat=c(dataset$Latitude[which(dataset$Projection=="NAD27")])
lon=c(dataset$Longitude[which(dataset$Projection=="NAD27")])
d=data.frame(lat, lon)

coordinates(d)=c("lat", "lon")
proj4string(d)=CRS("+init=epsg:4267")

CRS.new=CRS("+init=epsg:4269")
Nad27to83_projection=spTransform(d, CRS.new)
```

However, after the proj4string line, I receive the following error:

> Error in `proj4string<-`(`*tmp*`, value = new("CRS", projargs = > "+init=epsg:4267 +proj=longlat +datum=NAD27 +no_defs +ellps=clrk66 +nadgrids=@conus,@alaska,@ntv2_0.gsb,@ntv1_can.dat")) : 
>     Geographical CRS given to non-conformant data: -9.8732102099e+10  3.8108480000e+06 -1.0300835057e+02  3.7622300000e+05

In addition, after the spTransform line, I receive this error:

> Error in spTransform(d, CRS.new) : 
>     No transformation possible from NA reference system

I am stuck. Please let me know if anyone can help!

Comment: The second error is because you failed to assign the first CRS (this line: `proj4string(d)=CRS("+init=epsg:4267")`. If  your R object does not have a CRS, you can't project it to another one. The first error might have to do with coordinates' values being incompatible with the CRS which you want to assign, but you did not show a sample of such coordinates, so we can't know. Please, edit the question to provide a minimal, complete and reproducible example which we can work with. Tks.